# Как передать данные в iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Есть задача передать данные со страницы в `iframe`.

Сейачс я передалю данные из `iframe` на страницу, где их и принимаю. Но есть задача передавать данные обратно.

Вот рабочая функция, для отправки данных из `iframe` в `eventListener`, находящийся на стороне страницы, откуда `iframe` загружается.

```
  callParent = function (eventName) {
    window.parent.postMessage({
      'event': eventName,
      'token': 'traffic-widget'
    }, "*");
  }
```

А вот, собственно, и сам `eventListener`

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {...}, false);
```

Вся эта конструкция нормально работает, но трубется наладить дуплексную связь.

Как это сделать?

Если я устанавливаю `eventListener` на стороне `iframe`, то я начинаю получать  из самого `iframe`, но не получаю те, которые отправляю из основной страницы.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Максимум, чего мне удалось добиться, это ошибки: `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "addEventListener" on cross-origin object`.

Я так понимаю, что обойти это не так то просто, или вовсе не возможно.

Есть какие-то мнения на этот счёт?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: iframe на том-же домене находится ?

Comment: @EVG, нет, на другом.

Answer (score 3):

Собственно когда-то задавался этим вопросом тоже. Остались наброски, надеюсь вам поможет. Информация отправляется в `iframe` и выводится в блоке с id `reciveIframe` , после получения отправляется ответ и записывается в блок с id `test`. 
Проверить можете здесь [github page.](https://evgeniyvorobev.github.io/testpage/index.html) Но данный код будет работать при условии что сайты в зоне одного домена. Дело в том что это так называемые межсайтовые скрипты, и они блокируются политикой безопасности браузеров, подробнее почитайте тут [Error: Permission denied to access property “document”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333978/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document)

Страница на которой окно iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe" name="target" src="https://evgeniyvorobev.github.io/testpage/iframe.html" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" width="100%" ></iframe>
<div id="reciveIframe">а это инфа которую мы получили с iframe</div>

<script>
// отправка сообщения в iframe win.
window.onload = function(){
var win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow; // объект iframe
win.postMessage("Сообщение отправлено с страницы "+location.href,"https://evgeniyvorobev.github.io/testpage/iframe.html"); // отправляем сообщение в iframe ( после запятой адресс iframe )

function listener(event) { // получение сообщения из iframe
    event.origin == '' 
    document.getElementById("reciveIframe").innerHTML = event.origin + " прислал: " + event.data;
}
if (window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener("message", listener,false);
 } else {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
 }     
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function listener(event){
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = event.origin + " прислал: " + event.data;
                parent.postMessage('Вернули обратно произвольный текст Lorem ipsum dolor.','https://evgeniyvorobev.github.io/testpage/index.html')
            }
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener("message", listener,false);
            } else { // ie 8
                window.attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```